# Querying SQLAlchemy ORM objects from a CTE

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to use a CTE to reduce the size of the data scanned by my ORM query. I tried the the approach below:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

Base = declarative_base()

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"

    uuid = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    attr = Column(Integer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/")
    with Session(engine) as session:
        reduced = session.query(A).filter(A.attr > 3).cte()
        q = session.query(func.count(A.uuid)).select_from(reduced)
        print(q)
```

This results in SQL being generated that does a cartesian product of the A table and the CTE:

```
WITH anon_1 AS 
(SELECT a.uuid AS uuid, a.attr AS attr 
FROM a 
WHERE a.attr > %(attr_1)s)
 SELECT count(a.uuid) AS count_1 
FROM a, anon_1
```

I also tried adding an aliased(A, reduced) but the behaviour was the same. Is there any way to use a CTE to do this?

(In my actual code the CTE is used several times rather than just once in this test case)

Edit:

The code I was hoping to generate is something like:

```
WITH anon_1 AS 
(SELECT a.uuid AS uuid, a.attr AS attr 
FROM a 
WHERE a.attr > %(attr_1)s)
 SELECT count(anon_1.uuid) AS count_1 
FROM anon_1
```

Comment: Perhaps try `session.query(func.count(A.uuid)).join(reduced, A.uuid == reduced.c.uuid)`

Comment: The output I get with that is:
```
WITH anon_1 AS 
(SELECT a.uuid AS uuid, a.attr AS attr 
FROM a 
WHERE a.attr > %(attr_1)s)
 SELECT count(a.uuid) AS count_1 
FROM a JOIN anon_1 ON a.uuid = anon_1.uuid
```

Which I guess might work but is more complex than the SQL I would write myself and feels like I'm relying on the optimizer to do the right thing

Comment: Another option would be `session.query(func.count(A.uuid)).where(A.uuid.in_(select(reduced.c.uuid)))`

Comment: @WillNewton Can you include the SQL you are hoping to generate in the question?  That helps a lot.  It isn't clear to me what is expected.

Comment: @IanWilson I added an edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

Per updated question:

> The code I was hoping to generate is something like:
>
> WITH anon_1 AS
> (SELECT a.uuid AS uuid, a.attr AS attr
> FROM a
> WHERE a.attr > %(attr_1)s)
> SELECT count(anon_1.uuid) AS count_1
> FROM anon_1

If you want to only select from the CTE then just do that:

```py
q = session.query(func.count(reduced.c.uuid))
```

However, that does not address the issue from the question title

"Querying SQLAlchemy *ORM objects* from a CTE"

To do that you will need to query the object table and relate that to the CTE either by doing a `JOIN` or using `WHERE a.uuid IN (…)` as suggested in the comments.